# Flutter pytorch_lite Object Detection - Load changing model from Document Directory instead of the Asset folder

Tags: flutter, pytorch, object-detection, assets

I am quite new to Flutter and have been experimenting with the `pytorch_lite` library for a project at my University. The model has to detect round "buttons" with images of employees. If a new employee enters the company you can take pictures of the new button, and send them to a backend server where a new model based on the current one is trained and the app receives a new one. The `torchscript` file now also recognizes the new staff.

Since the assets folder in Flutter is read-only I must store the new files *(model.torchscript and classes.txt)* in a directory like with the `geApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` which has worked fine but if I want to load the model based on the path to the latest version in the document directory I get an error since the pytorch_lite library takes the path and then loads is via `rootBundle.load(path)` which only loads assets defined in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Is there a way to easily fix this, do I need to override the complete package or is there another solution to this problem?

For reference, this is the problematic code:

```dart
void loadModel() async {
  // Load base model in assets folder
  String modelPath = 'assets/objectDetection/best_8_Labels.torchscript';
  String labelPath = 'assets/objectDetection/classes_8_Labels.txt';

  // Define paths; in the json file, information about the latest models is stored
  final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  final jsonPath = '$directory/version.json';

  // If the files are available, load the model and the class file
  if (await File(jsonPath).exists()) {
    String jsonString = await File('$directory/version.json').readAsString();
    var modelName = json.decode(jsonString)['name'];
    var tempModelPath = '$directory/$modelName.torchscript';

    if (await File(tempModelPath).exists()) {
      modelPath = tempModelPath;
      labelPath = '$directory/$modelName.txt';
    }
  }

  // Load either the base model or the latest model
  // This is the problematic code segment that can't load the latest model
  modelObjectDetection = await PytorchLite.loadObjectDetectionModel(
    modelPath,
    8,
    640,
    640,
    labelPath: labelPath,
    objectDetectionModelType: ObjectDetectionModelType.yolov8,
  );
}
```

The app should have no problem with loading a file that is not specified in the `pubspec.yaml` and is not in the assets folder since this is read-only and the model gets updated with a new file every now and then.